# Populating a Table View from an Array while App is Running

Tags: nsmutablearray, tableview, populate

I am working on an app where the user can add NSString objects to an NSMutableArray and then the array is used to populate a Table View.

I have found lots of posts about populating a Table View from an NSMutableArray that is initialised with NSString objects in the viewDidLoad method, but nothing about populating from an NSMutableArray that the user can change while the app is running.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is a change in the data source, such as your NSMutableArray, you can reload the table view too for simplicity.

Or maybe you want some animation. For example, a new element is always added at the end of your mutable array, then you know you need to add another row at the end of the table view:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[yourArray addObject:aNewObject];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:yourArray.count-1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[tableView endUpdates];
```